# Data entering and multiple transitions in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have used d3.js drawing multiple shapes in a single svg. It's something like:

```
var draw = svg.selectAll("draw").data(data[0]).enter();
draw.append...  //Drawing first group of shapes
draw.append...  //Drawing second group of shapes
```

I know this might not be the best way, but it works fine. Now I want to add some transtions to it. I also have `data[1]`, and I want the drawing from `data[0]` lasting 5 seconds, and make a transition to `data[1]`. `data[0]`and `data[1]` have the same format and everything. 
I know the basic transition way, in this case, I can enter `data[0]` and `data[1]` at the start and then in every append, add `.transition().duration(2000).attr("...").delay(5000)`; but this is quite complex, if there is data[2], it means more code. How can I do this in the simpler way? Anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to create those transitions:

```
for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
  svg.selectAll("draw").data(data[i])
     .transition().duration(2000).delay(i * 5000)
     .attr(...);
}
```